# Access 2010 updating records from old database to new database

Tags: sql

I am recreating a new database from an older database, for many reasons. The employees are still using the old database. I have a draft copy of the old one with the same Client table.

I need to update my information such as `addresses`, `phone number` and other fields in the my new Client table from the old Client table before they can use it.

I am trying to write and SQL query to update new Client_table.newdatabase with old Client_table.olddatabase. Can anyone help?

Comment: Iam using the same server

Comment: Hi Mary, welcome to SO. Please take a moment and look into this to improve your questions and formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data you have in the old and new tables. Are there fields that match in both tables? if so and it is the names of clients, are they spelled the same in both tables?

I would also think about adding this to a third (new) table to prevent any type of data loss while trying this process. The query to use for a new third table is below.

```
SELECT NewTable.ClientName, OldTable.Address, OldTable.Phone
  INTO NewThirdTable
FROM NewTable
  INNER JOIN OldTable ON NewTable.MatchingField = OldTable.MatchingField;
```